# Getting key from the id of the entity using Appengine's NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a model based on ndb, while saving it, I stored 'id' field with current logged-in user's user id. (Why I am doing this? Actually this model used to be based on db.Model and key_name has this user's id. Now, I am converting it to ndb)

```
m= Modelclass(id = str(users.get_current_user().used_id()),
      --- Other fields ---
m.put()
```

This model's edit form sends this 'id' and I wanted to get corresponding 'key' from it. But, I got "Key id number is too long; received 'some big_number'". Tried both ways

```
Modelclass.get_by_id(<id>).key
```

OR

```
ndb.Key('Modelclass', <id>)
```

This is one case, there may be other cases where user can store some big number in 'id' field. In these scenarios, we can't extract key from 'id'. So, how to solve such a problem.

I am new to ndb. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your  value is an int, not a string.  But you converted it into a string when creating the entitiy.  There's a simple solution:

```
ndb.Key('Modelclass', str(<id>))
```

Good luck!